# Flutter - How to check bluetooth state using method channel in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

How to check bluetooth state using method channel in Flutter IOS
with the help of AppDelegate.swift and without using any third-party package.

I'm trying to implement checking bluetooth state using flutter method channel with the help of How  AppDelegate.swift but i'm unable to implement.

appDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import CoreBluetooth

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

    }
    
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

  // Bluetooth STATE - start -
     let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
     let bluetoothState = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "app/bleState",binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

     bluetoothState.setMethodCallHandler({
           (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in

           switch call.method{
           case "getBluetoothState":

        var centralManager:CBCentralManager!

           if (centralManager == nil) {

               centralManager=CBCentralManager(
                   delegate: self,
                   queue: nil,
                   options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: false]
               )

                if(centralManager.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
                result(true);
                }else{
                result(false)
                }

                }
                    default:
                    result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)

           }
         })


    // Bluetooth STATE - End -




    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Do you know how to use a method channel to invoke native code and get a response?  The Bluetooth state will be asynchronous and will change over time, so do you know how to set up the return event channel from native code?  Have you looked at CBCentralManager?

Comment: @Paulw11 i tried the above updated solution but getting error as " Cannot find 'CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn' in scope "
currently i have setup method channel to get response but i've no idea about event channel to get data as stream.

Comment: You are using some old code there.  You should compare `state` to `.poweredOn` but state is asynchronous. You need to create a long lived CBCentralManager and save it in a property.

Comment: @Paulw11 i don't have much idea about swift and IOS apis, if you can explain with the example code that would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following example to get bluetooth state using stream data

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import CoreBluetooth

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate,CBCentralManagerDelegate,FlutterStreamHandler {
  private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
  private var eventSink: FlutterEventSink?

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

   guard let controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController else {
        fatalError("rootViewController is not type FlutterViewController")
      }

   let bluetoothStateMethodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "method.flutter.io/bluetooth",
                                                 binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

   bluetoothStateMethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
         [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
         guard call.method == "getBluetoothState" else {
           result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
           return
         }
         self?.getBluetoothState(result: result)
       })

   let bluetoothStateEventChannel = FlutterEventChannel(name: "samples.flutter.io/bluetooth",
                                                 binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

   bluetoothStateEventChannel.setStreamHandler(self)
   centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil,options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: false])

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

   private func getBluetoothState(result: FlutterResult) {
     if(self.centralManager.state == .poweredOn) {
           result("Yes");
         } else {
           result("No");
         }
    }

   func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?,eventSink: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
                   self.eventSink = eventSink
                   return nil
               }

    func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
           eventSink = nil
           return nil
       }

  func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
   guard let eventSink = eventSink else {
        return
      }
             switch central.state {
                 case .poweredOn:
                   eventSink("on")


                 case .poweredOff:
                 eventSink("off")

                     // Alert user to turn on Bluetooth
                 case .resetting:
                 eventSink("resetting")

                     // Wait for next state update and consider logging interruption of Bluetooth service
                 case .unauthorized:
                 eventSink("unauthorized")

                     // Alert user to enable Bluetooth permission in app Settings
                 case .unsupported:
                  eventSink("unsupported")

                     // Alert user their device does not support Bluetooth and app will not work as expected
                 case .unknown:
                  eventSink("unknown")

                  default:
                  eventSink("not available")

                    // Wait for next state update
             }
         }


}
```

Flutter side to listen to the stream -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class BluetoothState extends StatefulWidget {
  const BluetoothState({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BluetoothState> createState() => _BluetoothStateState();
}

class _BluetoothStateState extends State<BluetoothState> {
  static const EventChannel eventChannel =
      EventChannel('samples.flutter.io/bluetooth');

  static const MethodChannel methodChannel =
      MethodChannel('method.flutter.io/bluetooth');

  String _bluetoothStatus = 'Bluetooth status: ';

  String _bleState = 'not';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(_onEvent, onError: _onError);
    _getBluetoothState();
  }

  void _onEvent(Object? event) {
    setState(() {
      _bluetoothStatus = "Bluetooth status: ${event == 'on' ? 'on' : 'off'}";
    });
  }

  void _onError(Object error) {
    setState(() {
      _bluetoothStatus = 'Battery status: unknown.';
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getBluetoothState() async {
    String bluetoothState;
    try {
      final String? result =
          await methodChannel.invokeMethod('getBluetoothState');
      bluetoothState = '$result%.';
    } on PlatformException {
      bluetoothState = 'Failed to get battery level.';
    }
    setState(() {
      _bleState = bluetoothState;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Text('status : $_bluetoothStatus'),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text('status init : $_bleState'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: example of using method and event channel in the official Flutter repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/platform_channel_swift